# NiFi ExecuteSQL Processor Timestamp

Tags: mysql, mariadb, apache-nifi

When extracting a table from MariaDb through the NiFi ExecuteSQL processor it is giving me the following error:

[image: Error message]

*org.apache.nifi.processor.exception.ProcessException: Value '0000-00-00 00:00:00' can not be represented as a java.sql.Timestamp;*

I am running NiFi version 1.1.1 and the datatype of the columns in question is a regular datetime type. I assume this is happening because of *null* values being present but is there a way to avoid having to escape all *null* values and have nifi handle this automatically.

Found the answer already.

['0000-00-00 00:00:00' can not be represented as java.sql.Timestamp error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11133759/0000-00-00-000000-can-not-be-represented-as-java-sql-timestamp-error)

Comment: Please edit the question that the error is text not a image...

Comment: Found the answer in a different Stackoverfow question. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11133759/0000-00-00-000000-can-not-be-represented-as-java-sql-timestamp-error