# Zero date value prohibited -- hibernate SQL JPA

Tags: java, mysql, spring-boot, hibernate, jpa

I am trying to execute a service with postman, but it is generating the next error

The table does not have information yet

```
public List<TestEntity> getFilterTest() {
        List<TestEntity> test= this.testRepositoryJPA.findAll();
        if(!stateBus.isEmpty()) {
            return test.stream()
                    .filter(x -> x.getState().toLowerCase().equals("PRUEBA"))
                    .collect(Collectors.toList());
        }
        return test;
    }
```

The line marks the error is the next

```
List<TestEntity> test= this.testRepositoryJPA.findAll();
```

JPA Entity

```
public interface TestRepositoryJPA extends JpaRepository<TestEntity, Integer> {
    final static Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(TestRepositoryJPA .class);
}
```

The pom

```
<!-- Conector/libreria de MYSQL para java -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>mysql</groupId>
    <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
    <scope>runtime</scope>
</dependency>
```

The Entity is

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonFormat;
import lombok.AllArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Data;
import lombok.NoArgsConstructor;
import org.apache.log4j.Logger;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Table;
import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.Date;

@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Entity
@Table(name = "test")
public class TestEntity implements Serializable {

    final static Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(TestEntity.class);
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -2463354084291480284L;

    @Id
    private Integer id;

    @Column(nullable = false , name = "a")
    private String  a;

    @JsonFormat(pattern="yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss")
    @Column(nullable = false , name = "b")
    private Date b;

    @Column(nullable = false , name = "c")
    private Integer  c;

    @JsonFormat(pattern="yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss")
    @Column(nullable = false , name = "d")
    private Date  d;

}
```

The table has the next data

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `Test`.`test` (
`id` INT NOT NULL,
`a` VARCHAR(45) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
`b` DATETIME NULL DEFAULT NULL,
`c` INT NULL DEFAULT NULL,
`d` DATETIME NULL DEFAULT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`id`))
ENGINE = InnoDB
DEFAULT CHARACTER SET = utf8;

The Datetime format is the next

> 2021-08-12 10:15:00

The query result is the next

[image]

The stacktrace is the next

> rg.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaSystemException: could not execute
> query; nested exception is
> org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: could not execute query
> at
> org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect.convertHibernateAccessException(HibernateJpaDialect.java:353)
> at
> org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect.translateExceptionIfPossible(HibernateJpaDialect.java:255)
> at
> org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.translateExceptionIfPossible(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:528)
> at
> org.springframework.dao.support.ChainedPersistenceExceptionTranslator.translateExceptionIfPossible(ChainedPersistenceExceptionTranslator.java:61)
> at
> org.springframework.dao.support.DataAccessUtils.translateIfNecessary(DataAccessUtils.java:242)
> at
> org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:153)
> at
> org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
> at
> org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor$CrudMethodMetadataPopulatingMethodInterceptor.invoke(CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor.java:178)
> at
> org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
> at
> org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:95)
> at
> org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
> at
> org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:212)
> at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy112.findAll(Unknown Source)  at
> sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)   at
> sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
> at
> sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
> at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)     at
> org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:344)
> at
> org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:205)
> at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy77.findAll(Unknown Source)   at
> com.co.umb.data.management.adapter.database.repository.StateBusDatabaseRepository.getActiveBus(StateBusDatabaseRepository.java:27)
> at
> com.co.umb.data.management.adapter.database.repository.StateBusDatabaseRepository$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$ad1e98c4.invoke()
> at
> org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:218)
> at
> org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(CglibAopProxy.java:771)
> at
> org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:163)
> at
> org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.proceed(CglibAopProxy.java:749)
> at
> org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:139)
> at
> org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
> at
> org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.proceed(CglibAopProxy.java:749)
> at
> org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:691)
> at
> com.co.umb.data.management.adapter.database.repository.StateBusDatabaseRepository$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$d0bb5e3b.getActiveBus()
> at
> com.co.umb.data.management.domain.service.ManagementService.executeHome(ManagementService.java:39)
> at
> com.co.umb.data.management.adapter.api.facade.ManagementFacade.getHomeContent(ManagementFacade.java:24)
> at
> com.co.umb.data.management.adapter.api.controller.ManagementController.getContentHome(ManagementController.java:44)
> at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)  at
> sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
> at
> sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
> at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)     at
> org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:190)
> at
> org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:138)
> at
> org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:105)
> at
> org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:879)
> at
> org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:793)
> at
> org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87)
> at
> org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1040)
> at
> org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:943)
> at
> org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1006)
> at
> org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:909)
> at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:660)     at
> org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:883)
> at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:741)     at
> org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231)
> at
> org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
> at
> org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)
> at
> org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
> at
> org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
> at
> org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:100)
> at
> org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)
> at
> org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
> at
> org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
> at
> org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:93)
> at
> org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)
> at
> org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
> at
> org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
> at
> org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201)
> at
> org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)
> at
> org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
> at
> org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
> at
> org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:202)
> at
> org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96)
> at
> org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:541)
> at
> org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:139)
> at
> org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92)
> at
> org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:74)
> at
> org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:343)
> at
> org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:373)
> at
> org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65)
> at
> org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:868)
> at
> org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1590)
> at
> org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
> at
> java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
> at
> java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
> at
> org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
> at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) Caused by:
> org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: could not execute query
> at
> org.hibernate.exception.internal.StandardSQLExceptionConverter.convert(StandardSQLExceptionConverter.java:47)
> at
> org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:113)
> at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2834)     at
> org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2813)  at
> org.hibernate.loader.Loader.listIgnoreQueryCache(Loader.java:2645)    at
> org.hibernate.loader.Loader.list(Loader.java:2640)    at
> org.hibernate.loader.hql.QueryLoader.list(QueryLoader.java:506)   at
> org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.list(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:400)
> at
> org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.HQLQueryPlan.performList(HQLQueryPlan.java:219)
> at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.list(SessionImpl.java:1412)   at
> org.hibernate.query.internal.AbstractProducedQuery.doList(AbstractProducedQuery.java:1565)
> at
> org.hibernate.query.internal.AbstractProducedQuery.list(AbstractProducedQuery.java:1533)
> at org.hibernate.query.Query.getResultList(Query.java:165)  at
> org.hibernate.query.criteria.internal.compile.CriteriaQueryTypeQueryAdapter.getResultList(CriteriaQueryTypeQueryAdapter.java:76)
> at
> org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.SimpleJpaRepository.findAll(SimpleJpaRepository.java:355)
> at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)  at
> sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
> at
> sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
> at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)     at
> org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.ImplementationInvocationMetadata.invoke(ImplementationInvocationMetadata.java:72)
> at
> org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryComposition$RepositoryFragments.invoke(RepositoryComposition.java:382)
> at
> org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryComposition.invoke(RepositoryComposition.java:205)
> at
> org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$ImplementationMethodExecutionInterceptor.invoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:549)
> at
> org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
> at
> org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.doInvoke(QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.java:155)
> at
> org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.invoke(QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.java:130)
> at
> org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
> at
> org.springframework.data.projection.DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.java:80)
> at
> org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
> at
> org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:367)
> at
> org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:118)
> at
> org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
> at
> org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:139)
> ... 78 more Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Zero date value
> prohibited    at
> com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:129)
> at
> com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:97)
> at
> com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:89)
> at
> com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:63)
> at
> com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:73)
> at
> com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLExceptionsMapping.translateException(SQLExceptionsMapping.java:99)
> at
> com.mysql.cj.jdbc.result.ResultSetImpl.getTimestamp(ResultSetImpl.java:914)
> at
> com.mysql.cj.jdbc.result.ResultSetImpl.getTimestamp(ResultSetImpl.java:959)
> at
> com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariProxyResultSet.getTimestamp(HikariProxyResultSet.java)
> at
> org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.TimestampTypeDescriptor$2.doExtract(TimestampTypeDescriptor.java:84)
> at
> org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.BasicExtractor.extract(BasicExtractor.java:47)
> at
> org.hibernate.type.AbstractStandardBasicType.nullSafeGet(AbstractStandardBasicType.java:257)
> at
> org.hibernate.type.AbstractStandardBasicType.nullSafeGet(AbstractStandardBasicType.java:253)
> at
> org.hibernate.type.AbstractStandardBasicType.nullSafeGet(AbstractStandardBasicType.java:243)
> at
> org.hibernate.type.AbstractStandardBasicType.hydrate(AbstractStandardBasicType.java:329)
> at
> org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.hydrate(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3087)
> at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.loadFromResultSet(Loader.java:1851)
> at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.hydrateEntityState(Loader.java:1779)
> at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.instanceNotYetLoaded(Loader.java:1752)
> at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.getRow(Loader.java:1600)     at
> org.hibernate.loader.Loader.getRowFromResultSet(Loader.java:743)  at
> org.hibernate.loader.Loader.processResultSet(Loader.java:1006)    at
> org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQuery(Loader.java:962)  at
> org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(Loader.java:352)
> at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2831)     ... 108 more
> Caused by: com.mysql.cj.exceptions.DataReadException: Zero date value
> prohibited    at
> com.mysql.cj.result.SqlTimestampValueFactory.localCreateFromTimestamp(SqlTimestampValueFactory.java:101)
> at
> com.mysql.cj.result.SqlTimestampValueFactory.localCreateFromTimestamp(SqlTimestampValueFactory.java:50)
> at
> com.mysql.cj.result.AbstractDateTimeValueFactory.createFromTimestamp(AbstractDateTimeValueFactory.java:87)
> at
> com.mysql.cj.protocol.a.MysqlTextValueDecoder.decodeTimestamp(MysqlTextValueDecoder.java:81)
> at
> com.mysql.cj.protocol.result.AbstractResultsetRow.decodeAndCreateReturnValue(AbstractResultsetRow.java:87)
> at
> com.mysql.cj.protocol.result.AbstractResultsetRow.getValueFromBytes(AbstractResultsetRow.java:241)
> at
> com.mysql.cj.protocol.a.result.ByteArrayRow.getValue(ByteArrayRow.java:91)
> ... 127 more

Comment: The code that you marked as Entity (in your question) is actually the repository.  Can you include your `Entity` definition as well, please?  - it seems like an annotation/definition is missing or misaligned

Comment: i added the entity

Comment: Does this answer your question? ['0000-00-00 00:00:00' can not be represented as java.sql.Timestamp error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11133759/0000-00-00-000000-can-not-be-represented-as-java-sql-timestamp-error)

Comment: In the `Date` field, the annotation indicates it cannot accept null values... check your DB for any records with this field either `NULL` or zeroed out..

Comment: @blurfus i added the image about the query

Comment: the definition of the table, allows NULL but the Entity does not - try changing this 
`@Column(nullable = false , name = "b")
    private Date b;` to this `@Column(nullable = true...)`

Comment: @AlejandroGonzalez a solution work for me. You can also try it. Please see my answer below.

Answer (score 11):

I faced same issue in a column namely modified_date type TIMESTAMP in MYSQL DB. I just added zeroDateTimeBehavior=convertToNull as query string parameter with datasource URL in application.properties file in springboot application and it worked for me.

**spring.datasource.url**=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/testdb?**zeroDateTimeBehavior=convertToNull**

[Here](https://www.taogenjia.com/2021/05/26/JDBC-Error-Java-sql-SQLException-Zero-Date-value-Prohibited/) is more details available.

[image: zeroDateTimeBehavior]

Answer (score 6):

Please check the database table columns with `date` type if any row contains zero value something like `0000-00-00`.

Comment: This is an issue that I am facing, but I cannot change the data in the database, how can I work around this?

Comment: Ok!! Will post if I found something.

Answer (score 1):

It is an exception that is returned when we have date field with zeros like:

> 0000-00-00

In my case, for example, removing/editing the existing field with zeros solved my problem.
By depending on your case, you can filter invalid date fields like this and handle them to avoid this kind of exception.

Answer (score -1):

In my case, the error was because my entity has a null field, then I changed the fields

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonFormat;
import lombok.AllArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Data;
import lombok.NoArgsConstructor;
import org.apache.log4j.Logger;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Table;
import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.Date;

@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Entity
@Table(name = "test")
public class Test implements Serializable {

    final static Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(StateDriverEntity.class);
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -2463354084291480284L;

    @Id
    private Integer id;

    @Column(nullable = false , name = "a")
    private String  a;

    @Column(nullable = false , name = "b")
    private Date b;

    @Column(nullable = false , name = "c")
    private Integer  c;

    @Column(nullable = false , name = "d")
    private Date  d;

}
```

The field c has this name

```
stateActive
```

The error was generated because when the JPA generates the mapping, it converts in camel case

```
state_active
```

The columns does not have data, as consequence the nullable generates an error.

**The solution was**

Changed the column's name from `stateActive` to `state_active`

**Note**: it was not necessary to change the `spring.datasource.url`

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://a:a@local/c?reconnect=true
```